# Finite translation surfaces with Veech groups that are non-elementary Fuchsian groups of the second kind?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

I know that all Veech surfaces have Veech groups which are Fuchsian groups of the first kind and that there exist finite translation surfaces with Veech groups that are [elementary Fuchsian groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3516) of the second kind. I also know that there are [wild translation surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.06877) with Veech groups that are non-elementary Fuchsian groups of the second kind. But do there exist any tame, finite translation surfaces with Veech groups that are non-elementary Fuchsian groups of the second kind?